# Erased External Hard Drive after installing Ubuntu

Tags: boot, system-installation, external-hdd

I was trying to reformat my old Windows laptop and replace the OS with Ubuntu 14.04.4 using **Unetbootin**. I did not have a Flash pen drive at the time so I used my external hard drive to boot and install Ubuntu. The external HD contained more than 300GB of files in one folder plus the Ubuntu ISO file. During installation, I chose to delete all Windows related files in the laptop and replace it with Ubuntu (it was an option in the Ubuntu installation), thinking that when I restart the laptop after installation, Ubuntu would have replaced Windows in drive C.

Unfortunately, Ubuntu was installed in the laptop but it did not replace the Windows (so I can both boot in Windows in Ubuntu). Worse, all files in the external HD were deleted, and were replaced by files in drive C of my old Windows laptop.

My goal is to recover all the lost files in the External HD. My plan is to use Recuva. But to complicate things, I cannot access my external hard drive using a Windows laptop. Although it is recognized as a "device", it does not appear as an as an option in "This PC". Note that this external HD is accessible through a Ubuntu laptop.

So my question are:

1) How can I make the external HD accessible using a laptop with Windows OS?

2) With the "background story" in mind, what steps can I do to recover the files, if you think Recuva is not enough?

Before writing this, I have read some of the related questions and I would like to say that I am grateful for the help this community offers to end-users like me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows will not be able to read Ubuntu (ext4) formatted drives. I have no experience with Recuva, and whether it can recover from ext4 formatted drives.

What I know however is that you will be able to recover those files, or directories that were not yet overwritten using Open Source Linux tools such as [**TestDisk**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/286181/how-do-i-recover-my-accidentally-lost-windows-partitions-after-installing-ubuntu). This tool can be installed in an Ubuntu live session (i.e. by booting from an Ubuntu installation USB choosing "try out Ubuntu").

To do so you need the following:

- a working Internet connection on the live Ubuntu (prefer LAN over wireless).
- an Ubuntu USB drive from where you can boot.
- a spare drive to store the rescued files on.

In case TestDisk fails to recover all files we may also give PhotoRec a chance.

Comment: Hi Takkat. Thanks for this fast, brief, and useful explanation. I feel very relieved to know that there is a chance that the files will be recovered. I will try this and will share my experience. I am very grateful for your kindness. Thank you.